# Generating correlated standard normals

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, monte-carlo

Suppose I want to generate three standard normals $X, Y, Z$ with correlation
matrix given by

$R$=
$ \begin{pmatrix} 1.0 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\ 0.2 & 1.0 & 0.2 \\ 0.2 & 0.2 & 1.0\end{pmatrix}$

How would I do this?

Edit: I would give a starting point for discussion, but I don't understand what it means to "generate" a variable to begin with. I am trying to further my understanding before finals.

Comment: A shortcut to the answer below is to introduce $(U,V,W)$ i.i.d. standard normal and to define $$X=aU+bV+bW\qquad Y=bU+aV+bW\qquad Z=bU+bV+aW$$ where $(a,b)$ solves $$a^2+2b^2=1\qquad 2ab+b^2=0.2.$$

Comment: Where do these equations on the bottom come from? Is there a specific property of correlation being used?

Comment: Nothing specific, but the fact that $E(U^2)=E(V^2)=E(W^2)=1$, $E(UV)=E(VW)=E(WU)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform to a basis in which the matrix is diagonal (its eigenvalues are $1.4$ and $0.8$ and the corresponding eigenspaces are the space spanned by $(1,1,1)$ and its orthogonal complement, respectively) and generate three independent variables with normal distributions with variances given by the diagonal elements.

Comment: How would this change if, say, I wanted X, Y, Z to have means and variances 0,1 and 2 & 4, 16 and 25 respectively?

Comment: @user151876: The means are irrelevant; just do whatever you would for mean zero and then add the desired means. About the variances: I'm not sure what you mean -- you're specifying only the variances and not the covariances -- are the covariances meant to be $0.2$ as before?

Comment: Let's say the question didn't give me the above correlation matrix but instead gave me the means and variances from above. Is that possible?

Comment: @user151876: You can't generate samples if you don't know the joint distribution, and the means and variances without the covariances don't determine the joint distribution. Perhaps you mean that the covariances are implied to be zero?